# swap(int &a, int &b) and swap(int *a, int *b). What is difference?

Tags: c++

```
void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
    int iTemp ;
    iTemp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = iTemp;

}
void swap2(int &a, int &b)
{
    int iTemp;
    iTemp = a;
    a = b;
    b = iTemp;
}
```

What are the difference between `swap2(&a, &b)` and `swap(*a,*b)`. Although, final result is the same.

Comment: `void swap2(int &a, int &b)` is not valid in `C`

Answer (score 0):

```
void swap(int *a, int *b)
```

You are expecting the variable to pass by pointer (a value of the type pointer to int)

---

```
void swap2(int &a, int &b)
```

you are expecting the variable to pass by reference (which is the the address of an integer variable)

---

However, the two previous statements are the same technically.

**1)** The first one is called like this:

```
int a,b;
swap(&x,&y);
```

the other one:

```
int a,b;
swap2(x,y);
```

**2)** You can pass A `NULL` or `nullptr` to the first one. However, you can not for the second one.

As far as I remember, in google c++ style guide, they prefer the first one since it is obvious that the parameter may be changed.